# Pandas convert ALL columns to a int64 type

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following code:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [2], 'b': ['1'], 'c': ['3'], 'd': [5]})
print(df.dtypes)
```

And obviously I get

```
a     int64
b    object
c    object
d     int64
dtype: object
```

as an output. I would like to map each of the columns to int64, but automatically - I don't want to go through all the columns manually and set each one of them to int64. Is there a one-liner or a crafty way to do it?

P.S. I know I can change the type to int64 by using `pd.to_numeric(df['b'])`, for example. I want to do this for ALL the columns.

Comment: NVM, I did it: df.apply(pd.to_numeric, axis=1)

Comment: Post it as an answer, accept it to close the ticket

Comment: I will accept Ynjxsjmh's answer, because it seems better than mine

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`pandas.DataFrame.astype`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.astype.html)

```py
df = df.astype('int64')
```

```
print(df)

a    int64
b    int64
c    int64
d    int64
dtype: object
```